# Anatomically Correct Oannes

Tags: anatomy, merfolk, anatomically-correct

The Oannes is a being from Mesopotamian Mythology. It is a hybrid of a human and fish, with a unique anatomy

They are are humanoid in posture, with a body, tail, and head like a fish, and the arms and legs of a human. They also have a humanoid head set in the fish' throat. They have human-like intelligence, and both faces have their normal functions. The fish head has no neck and faces up, whereas the human head faces forward. The legs are normally placed, and the arms are positioned as in humans relative to the human face

**How would this strange being's anatomy work?**

Comment: I used a picture in my answer, and a photo plus some links would strengthen the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Head

The heads are the main issue with the Oannes. Firstly, the brain can be placed in the fish braincase, enlarged to match human intelligence. The human head could be reduced to just the face, to make it easier to fit in. It would have all of the facial bones, including the mandible. This should also be enough bone for the muscles of the face and jaw. The cranial nerves would be duplicated, with one set going around the fish pharynx to the human face. The nose and mouth would be connected directly to the fish pharynx. This pharynx would have a set of lungs, with a human-like respiratory tract to breathe air and talk

## Arms

While not as convoluted, the arms still have issues. A fish' forelimbs are normally on its head, yet the Oannes' arms are more humanoid in position. The arms could be placed in the middle of the spine, with humanoid shoulders on the ribcage under the flesh. While this is perfect with the skeleton, there are muscular issues, as this interrupts the main muscle blocks. One solution is to only start these blocks after the arms, with a more humanoid muscle structure above

## Legs

The legs are a further issue. While human legs are mammalian and adapted for a lack of tail, the fish's tail is thick and has little room for such limbs. One possibility could be to give them a structure similar to fish-tailed tetrapods like cetaceans and ichthyosaurs. While this will leave the leg bones floating, it's not so different from the floating scapula, which much larger creatures are able to deal with

Answer (score 1):

## One Face for Each Lifestyle:

Your [Oannes](https://mythus.fandom.com/wiki/Oannes) is superbly adapted to the role of an amphibian sapient being. Portrayed as highly intelligent, they bring wisdom to humanity.

But on a world where humans are a dominant, aggressive species extremely well adapted to land only, your oannes are at a disadvantage on land. So their ability to move on land has evolved to mimic humans. Their limbs look human, and their secondary head mimics a human face to allow empathy from humans. This is so prevalent that oannes have carved out a niche with humans as divine beings. The constant long-distance travel early in history have given them a reputation as being wise, but that's as much a function of travel and learning as anything else.

The face allows consumption of food while bipedal, and a full set of human senses on land. There are likely lungs, but there would certainly be advantages to the oannes if they posses both lungs and gills. Arms and legs enable a slightly awkward ability to walk on land and use tools, while the tail and scales enable faster movement and greater maneuverability in water. The stance is likely more akin to that of a dinosaur, with a forward leaning body. The forward fish head allows wide-angle vision and a different stance in the water. The dual heads also mean they don't have an easily breakable neck.

While not as fast swimmers as fish,  they might be similar to something like a seal in terms of maneuverability. A fish tail allows greater thrust and the arms and legs in water likely serve to allow maneuverability. Taking advantage of both environments gives them the ability to maximize food sources.

Intelligence and tool use allow oannes to exceed the success of more physically capable sea life, while their superior adaptations to marine life compared to humans allow oannes to fulfill a valuable symbiotic role with humans.

The habitat would logically be along coasts and on islands, exploiting a wide range of niches.
[image: oannes]

Those of us old enough to remember Scooby-doo might remember this guy. The awkwardness of this fish-man hybrid is solved with the second set of mouth/sensory organs.

[image: shark-man]